# Crop and save images as circle JCrop

Tags: c#, jquery, jcrop

I have a page that let users upload a picture and from that picture they have to make a selection to work with. This selection has to be a circle with specific dimensions. for acheiving this i used the below --

```
 .jcrop-holder div
        {
            -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
            -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
            border-radius: 50% !important;
            margin: -1px;
        }
```

Now I want to save a circle of that image..currently it saves as a square.How would one create a round image from a circle selection? Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

The work around I have done is to do the following:

```
$('#<%=imgUpload.ClientID%>').Jcrop({
            onSelect: SelectCropArea,
            boxWidth: 600,
            boxHeight: 600,
            maxSize: [500, 500],
            minSize: [100, 100],
            aspectRatio: 2/2
        });
```

So as you can see, what I have done is: doesnt matter which size the image is; it will always be viewed as 600x600 and limited crop size such as min and max 100 and 500.

Further more after user have cropped it, image is still a square but to over lay with radius as such:

```
<div style="height: 94px; width: 94px; border-radius: 100px; -webkit-border-radius: 100px;overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 30px; left: 50px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">


<img src="../Images/user.png" runat="server" id="imgProfile" alt="Profile Picture" style="width:100px;"/>
```

This should help with work around.

Hope it helps.

Regards